# how can I calculate effect sizes (cohen's d) with emmeans

Tags: emmeans

I wonder how I can calculate effect sizes for significant post-hoc comparisons.
I first ran a 2x2x2 repeated measures ANOVA and then set-up custom post-hoc comparisons. Two of them are of interest to me and I want to calculate the effect sizes (cohen’s d). However, I get error messages when I try to use the eff_size function. I really would appreciate your help! Thank you in advance !

AOV model:
Aov_Dynamo_LPP <- aov_ez(
id = 'Subject', dv = 'Amplitude', within = c('Picture','Communication','Condition'),
data = Dynamo_LPP_long
)

Full Table of custom contrasts:
Contrast_Dynamo_LPP_ofint
contrast              estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
LPP_Receiving_Free      1.4291 0.265 29   5.392  0.0001
LPP_Receiving_Compete   1.6157 0.367 29   4.405  0.0016
LPP_Sending_Compete     0.3884 0.225 29   1.729  0.6959
LPP_Sending_Free        0.0421 0.227 29   0.185  1.0000
LPP_Pic1_Compete        1.8784 0.376 29   4.995  0.0003 (!!want to calculate effect size!!)
LPP_Pic2_Compete       -0.1258 0.322 29  -0.391  1.0000
LPP_Pic1_Free           2.0331 0.297 29   6.853  <.0001 ((!!want to calculate effect size!!)
LPP_Pic2_Free           0.5620 0.289 29   1.947  0.5316
LPP_Sending_Pic1        0.0530 0.299 29   0.177  1.0000
LPP_Sending_Pic2        0.3993 0.215 29   1.862  0.5963
LPP_Receiving_Pic1     -0.1017 0.265 29  -0.384  1.0000
LPP_Receiving_Pic2     -0.2884 0.299 29  -0.966  0.9934

I tried this formula: eff_size(Contrast_Dynamo_LPP_ofint, sigma = sigma(Aov_Dynamo_LPP), edf = 29)

Error message:
Fehler in X[ii, ii, drop = FALSE] %*% y[ii] : nicht passende Argumente
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In nobs.default(object, use.fallback = use.fallback) :
no 'nobs' method is available

Comment: I think the problem may be that sigma() doesn't work for your model. Perhaps it will work if you run it with just the value of the error SD that you see in the model summary.

Comment: thank you - I will try that!